# Changing the colors of each hist facet on facetgrid?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm using the titanic dataset from kaggle, and I would like to differentiate the facets of Survivors (1) vs Non-Survivors (0) via different colors.

Here is my current FacetGrid:

[image]

The left facets(graphs) are of those who didn't survive. I want those to be colored in red. The right facets are fine the way the are at the moment.

So my desired output will look something like this.
I would also like to add a simple legend to each facet (*red color* = 'Died', *blue color* = 'Survived')
[image]

Here is a sample dataframe `Full Set`

```
               Sex    Survived
PassengerId                  
1              male         0
2            female         1
3            female         1
4            female         1
5              male         0
6              male         0
7              male         0
8              male         0
9            female         1
10           female         1
11           female         1
12           female         1
13             male         0
14             male         0
15           female         0
16           female         1
17             male         0
18             male         1
19           female         0
```

Here is the code I currently have:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style ="ticks")
h=sns.FacetGrid(Full_set, col ='Survived', row ='Sex', palette = 'Set1', size =2, aspect =2)
h =h.map(plt.hist, 'Age')


plt.show()
```

I went through the FacetGrid's API in the documentation (http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html#seaborn.FacetGrid) but I didn't see any examples or a way to do what I desire.
EDIT:

I tried `hue` but the problem I was having was that on a hist, the graphs ended up overlapping, and fully covering the graph with lesser values. 
Thank you!

Comment: Did you try `hue`?

Comment: Yes, I tried `hue` but the problem I was having was that on a hist, the graphs ended up overlapping, and fully covering the graph with lesser values.

Comment: @moondra, Can you try: `g = sns.FacetGrid(Full_set, row="Sex", col="Survived", hue_kws={'color': ['r', 'b']}, hue="Survived");
g.map(plt.hist, "Age")` ?

Comment: Yeah, this seems to be working. Thank you.  So by assigning hue to two colors, you were able to create separate graphs, instead of having them overlap? Is that the trick? 
 Your solution is a little tricky but I think I somewhat understand it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `hue` parameter works similar to a `groupby` object. So, when the `hue` is set according to the *Survived* column, it becomes a separate entity for it's unique values(namely, 0 and 1). Then using it's keywords arg, input the colors you want to display for each grouped instance(0→red, 1→blue).

***Possibility 1:***

```
d = {'color': ['r', 'b']}
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row='Sex', col='Survived', hue_kws=d, hue='Survived')
g.map(plt.hist, 'Age')
```

***Possibility 2:***

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row='Sex', col='Survived', hue='Survived', palette='Set1')
g.map(plt.hist, 'Age')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I never thought of setting column #and# hue as 'survived'. I always assumed,  it was always one or the other.

Comment: You don't need `hue_kws` here; use the `palette` parameter.